# Which of these is correct- 'in a given deadline' or 'by a given deadline'?

Tags: prepositions

While writing content for a website, I stuck at this sentence:

> Our developers can complete the project ***by a given deadline***.

I read [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22in%20a%20given%20deadline%22) that '**in** a given deadline' can also be written, however, I am not sure about its correctness. 
[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20given%20deadline%2C%20by%20a%20given%20deadline&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20a%20given%20deadline%3B%2Cc0) also shows that 'in a given deadline' is not found.

Now my question is: Can we write 'in a given deadline' for 'by a given deadline'?

Comment: Where did you read this "in a given deadline" can be written too? You should always provided sources when possible. Anyway, it sounds strange. I've never heard it.

Comment: You are perhaps looking for "within" rather than "in"

Comment: Can we use 'within' instead of 'by' for my sentence, @Leo?

Comment: Yes. Within would be perfectly fine. In would not.

Comment: As your Ngram shows, the expression of choice is *by a given deadline.* I have never heard *in a given deadline*, and just because one person used it, it would not dissuade me from *by a given deadline*.

Comment: @RucheerM I'm not sure what you are asking. You were given better alternatives by native speakers but you continue to ask can we use "in a given deadline". Upon whose authority do you want this to be answered by? If you just want a straight yes or no answer, then fine, no.

Answer (score 1):

> Our developers can complete the project by the deadline.

There are many wordy alternatives, but this is probably the simplest.

Comment: as for the ngrams https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+a+deadline%2Cin+a+deadline%2Cwithin+a+deadline%2C+by+the+deadline&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithin%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cby%20the%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20the%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20the%20deadline%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of whether "in" is an acceptable substitute.

Comment: @Catija they are all worded weirdly regardless of the acceptability -- such that the point of the sentence hasn't changed in any of the proposed alternatives.

Comment: Not to me... if this sentence appears on a bullet list of capabilities for a company, meaning "Here are the reasons you should hire us" - the current phrasing is actually quite correct. Your version does not suit that as well.

Comment: Ah I think I see, in that case, they would most likely lean to something like `Our developers can complete your project by your deadline.` or even just `on time`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the phrases "in a deadline or within a deadline" to replace the phrase "by a deadline". They sound correct grammatically, though not used commonly. It's more usual or idiomatic to use the verb meet before a deadline. The use of "by a deadline" is preferred to that of "in/within a deadline", and the use of the phrase "meet a deadline" is the most common of these four phrases.

So you can say:

Our developers can meet a deadline for the project.

You can use the verb set or given, though not necessary,  after the deadline if you want:

Our developers can meet a deadline set/given for the project.

Comment: A *time* is a *time span*, a length of time. A deadline is the end of a time span. Second, most  or all those Ngram results for *in a deadline* are false positives. Additionally, the use of *given* is quite common and not redundant.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet+a+deadline%2Cby+a+deadline%2Cin+a+deadline%2Cwithin+a+deadline&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeet%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithin%20a%20deadline%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

`by` vs. `within`

Personally both options "feel" okay to me.

[image]

Comment: What about 'in'? Would you add it as well in your answer?

Comment: I understand the meaning of "in a given deadline" but I wouldn't personally use it.

Comment: Is it okay to use it instead of 'by'?